8086 Assembly Language 2 digit integer printing
Why is 42 not printed out?
The output is 0M instead of 42
TEST2   PROC

    mov arrCount[0], 42

    mov al, arrCount[0]
    mov bx, 10
    xor dx, dx
    div bx

    mov bl, al
    mov bh, ah

    mov ah, 02h
    add bh, '0'
    mov dl, bh
    int 21h

    mov ah, 02h
    add bl, '0'
    mov dl, bl
    int 21h

    ret

TEST2   ENDP

MAIN    PROC    FAR

    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    
;   call    TEST1
    call    TEST2

    mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h

    MAIN    ENDP
END     MAIN


div bx puts the quotient into ax and the remainder into dx. Also you are printing the digits swapped.

In 8086 there's a byte-sized and a word-sized division.
The byte-sized div divides AX by whichever byte-sized source operand you provide, eg. div bl. The outcome is to be found in AL for the quotient and in AH for the remainder.
The word-sized div divides DX:AX by whichever word-sized source operand you provide, eg. div bx. The outcome is to be found in AX for the quotient and in DX for the remainder.
One of the errors that you got is that you perform the word-sized division, yet expect the outcome from the byte-sized division. Additionally you forgot to zero the AH register beforehand and you printed the digits in the wrong order.
Word-sized solution
mov al, arrCount[0]
mov ah, 0
xor dx, dx
mov bx, 10
div bx         ; Word-sized DX:AX / BX

mov bl, al     ; Quotient AX
mov bh, dl     ; Remainder DX

mov ah, 02h
add bl, '0'
mov dl, bl
int 21h

mov ah, 02h
add bh, '0'
mov dl, bh
int 21h

Byte-sized solution
mov al, arrCount[0]
mov ah, 0
mov bl, 10
div bl         ; Byte-sized AX / BL

mov bl, al     ; Quotient AL
mov bh, ah     ; Remainder AH

mov ah, 02h
add bl, '0'
mov dl, bl
int 21h

mov ah, 02h
add bh, '0'
mov dl, bh
int 21h

Byte-sized solution but a bit better!
mov al, arrCount[0]
cbw            ; Numbers range from 0 to 99
mov dl, 10
div dl         ; Byte-sized AX / DL

add ax, "00"   ; To ASCII
mov dx, ax     ; Quotient AL and Remainder AH

mov ah, 02h
int 21h

mov dl, dh
int 21h


For 2-digit numbers we can also use aam to divide by an immediate 10 instead of needing mov dl, 10. (It puts the digits in the other order from div).  Displaying Time in Assembly
